# Spring + ibatis + String matching

Tags: string, spring, pattern-matching, string-matching, ibatis

I have a Spring application integrated with ibatis.

I am calling some third party application from where I am getting a String message (a message is combination of messages, there are Strings concatenated with \ delimiter to concatenate the different messages from the third party) as output. 
I have to filter this output based on String matching. There are some 150 other Strings. If the output message contains any string out of 150 messages, i have to add some functionality.

I need suggestions to implement it. I am thinking to put 150 Strings in table as the count may increase in future. The Output may contain either no message out of this 150, or any number of combinations with these 150 messages.

I am new to Spring. please tell me how to get these messages from database, since i do not have an id to fetch them or shall I get all of them as list and then compare the output string from the third party. Also please tell me If it wise to keep these messages in database or I can keep them in some property file as well, which one will be better in performance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hof often will new messages have to be added? Will they have to be added during runtime or just with a new release of your software? How long are the messages (min/average/max)? Are there possibile differences (for example, upper/lower case) or are the strings exactly the same all the time?

Comment: Oh, and as an idea: You do have an id, since the hash code of the Strings would probably qualify for that quite well.

Comment: Also, another question: Is the action you have to take always the same or are there different actions for some strings?

Comment: Actually the messages are from the third party systems, which is a legacy system. So I am not sure how many messages in total they have. As an when testing will proceed, they want me to add the messages. Also the solution should be independent of the messages, so that once the development is over, even then the messages can be added as configuration.

Comment: could you please tell me about hashcode, how can i make use of this.  About the third comment, the action is basically, each output message is combination of warnings and errors, I have this lit of 150 error messages, I just have to remove the other warning messages from the final message and just have to keep the error messages. E.g. if i get a message as "ABCDEF" from the third party, I have in database the list of actual errors,say(only B and EF are errors), then i need to compare the entire "ABCDEF" with B and EF and return "B|E|F" along with some other details associated with B,E and F.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's start with some possibilities:

IF you will only be adding a few messages in the future and only do so with new releases, then storing the messages in an enum would be a viable choice:

```
enum ErrorMessage {

    SOME_MESSAGE("something, bla bla"),
    SOME_OTHER_MESSAGE("something_else"),
    ...;

    private String message;
    private ErrorMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public static ErrorMessage getByErrorMessage(String message) {
        for(ErrorMessage errorMessage: message) {
            if (errorMessage.message.equals(message)) {
                return errorMessage;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static boolean exists(String message) {           
        return getByErrorMessage(message) != null;
    }
}
```

Please note that this version is quite primitive and could be improved by adding all the messages into a static Set:

```
static Set<String> messagesCache = new Hashset<String>();

//in constructor:
messagesCache.add( message );

// better exists() method:
public static boolean exists(String message) {
    return messagesCache.contains(message);
}
```

Or, as with other solutions, you could only store the actual hashcode of your strings. A hashcode is simple a numeric representation of your string and will be unique enough for you to identify it. Same solution as above:

```
static Set<String> messagesHashCodes = new Hashset<String>();

//in constructor:
messagesHashCodes .add( message.hashCode() );

// better exists() method:
public static boolean exists(String message) {
    return messagesHashCodes .contains(message.hashCode());
}
```

(Of course, it would be a good idea to check for null values, etc.)

The enum version has one big advantage, if you want to have DIFFERENT actions taken for some of the actions, you can code them into the enum, for example...

```
SOME_MESSAGE_REQUIRING_AN_ACTION("...") {

    @Override
    public void doAction(StringBuilder finalString) {
        ...doSomething.
    }
}


...

public void doAction(StringBuilder finalString) {
    finalString.append( this.message );
    finalString.append( SOME_SEPERATOR );
}

public void static doAction(StringBuilder builder, String errorMessage) {
    if (exists(errorMessage)) {
    }
}
```

In this example, you CAN override the doAction method in each enum value, if it should do more/something else than append the message to the StringBuilder. It would also be a nice touch to add some "NULL_MESSAGE" to the enum List that does nothing and is only there to allow easier handling:

```
UNKNOWN_MESSAGE(null) {

    @Override
    public void doAction(StringBuilder finalString) {
        // do nothing here
    }
}

public static ErrorMessage getByErrorMessage(String message) {
    for(ErrorMessage errorMessage: message) {
        if (errorMessage.message != null && errorMessage.message.equals(message)) {
            return errorMessage;
        }
    }
    return UNKNOWN_MESSAGE;
}
```

This way, you can simple give every single string into your enum method doAction(StringBuilder, String) and get the result: If a message fits, it is added (and some other action taken), if not, it will be ignored, null checks included.

On the other hand, if you messages change quite often, then you might not do a release for such a change but keep the values in a database. In this case, I would use the hashCode() of the message as an id (as I said, unique enough, typically) and load the whole thing into memory when the application starts, allowing you, for example, to build again a Set of hashcodes to compare your errorMessages' hashcodes against.

```
protected void init() {
    // load all error Messages from the database
    // put them into a Map<String, String> (hashCode -> Value) or even just a Set<String> (hashcodes)
}
```